# minecraft-commands: Multiple commands on one line?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-bukkit

Is there a way to put multiple commands on one line?

I would like to be able to have a command that will make the nearest player run MULTIPLE commands, something like this:

`/sudo @p command1; sudo @p command2`

(Note: I'm on a Bukkit server using Essentials, that's why I have the command `sudo`.)

That way, the semicolon will signal a line break, but the first slash indicated that the player is running a command, so another slash is not needed.

This would be used for chat commands, command blocks and more.

Comment: Not on vanilla there isn't; but I'm unsure about Bukkit with Essentials.

Comment: I'm not confident this should have been closed, since this is a broader topic (chat commands + command blocks), so I've voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vanilla minecraft it is possible to have multiple commands run by having only one command block powered, but you have to at some point during the execution to split each command into their own command block/command block minecart. This is the basic concept of One-CommandBlock creations. The idea is to summon falling sand entities riding each other to place multiple blocks at the same time.

The bottom most block of this tower should be a stone block, a redstone block, the a command block to fill one side of the tower with redstone blocks. The top command will have to clear the tower.

Comment: Thanks but could I maybe get some sort of tutorial?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, dude. Sorry I apparently never marked this as the answer lol